# calculate project progress when toggling todo item

Tags: algorithm

I'm making a todo app , and I thought of some ways to spice it up so I implemented a project progress feature . so in the app you can create `projects`  each project can have `todolists` and each todolist can have `todos`.

 so the when user toggles a todo I  recalculate the project's progress this way

```
const todoContirubutioToProjectPorgess=1/projectTodosTotalCount
project.progress += todoContirubutioToProjectPorgess
```

this works fine if the todolists in project have the same number of todos , but when they aren't this doesn't really make sense because , for example let's consider these cases:

case 1

```
project : [
   todoList1[todo1,todo2],
   todoList2[todo3,todo4]
]
//todo1's contribution to project's progress is the same todo3's so it works here
```

case 2

```
project : [
   todoList1[todo1,todo2],
   todoList2[todo3,todo4,todo5]
]
//todo1's contribution to project's progress is bigger than todo3 , since todo1 makes 50% of todoList1 and todo3 makes only 30% todoList2
```

I tried this

```
const todoListContirubutioToProjectPorgess  =  todoListTodosCount/projectTodosTotalCount
const todoContirubutioToPorgess =  1/todoListContirubutioToProjectPorgess  
project.progress += todoContirubutioToPorgess
```

but it didn't work as I expected , what do you think about this and how would you go about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let there be `x` todo lists, and the numbers of tasks be `[t1, t2, t3, ...tx]`.
Contribution of each todo list = `100/x %`
Contribution of each item in list 1 = `(100/x) / t1%` = `100/(x*t1) %`.
Contribution of each item in list 2 = `(100/x) / t2%` = `100/(x*t2) %`.
Contribution of each item in list x = `(100/x) / tx%` = `100/(x*tx) %`.

For each task, you need only two variables: total number of lists and the number of tasks in the current list. Then use the above formula to get the progress increment.